# adding x and y into single column in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, concatenation

I have always use the field calculator to retrieve my x and y coords ($x, $y), but this ends up with 2 separate columns, which I then have to manually concatenate.

Is there a way to do this easily within QGIS? - perhaps using the expression box? I feel like there must be some easy expression similar to concatenate in excel (e.g. $x, ", ", $y).

Answer (score 5):

```
$x || ', ' || $y
```

|| concatenates strings.

Single quotes are used for adding in text.

From @TeddyTedTed in the comments:

To round the coordinates to x decimal places use the ROUND(number, x) function:

For example 3 decimals:

```
ROUND($x, 3) || ', ' || ROUND($y, 3)
```

Comment: Just to add one thing, it may be useful to round the coordinates down to avoid too many unnecessary decimal places. To do so use the ROUND() function like this:
`ROUND($x, 3) || ', ' || ROUND($y, 3)`

Comment: Thanks, made an edit.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm just getting NULL when I try the same?

Comment: Are your geometries points, or lines, or polygons? Does the preview show the correct result? What type of field are you inserting the data into, it should be string?

Comment: Thanks, working now - may have been trying whole number (integer), or perhaps didn't increase the output field length from default 10...